# How to open diagram exported in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, uml

I've got an issue with opening xml file of a database diagram, that has been exported using IntelliJ IDE.

Here is example of IntelliJ generated file (empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Diagram>
  <ID>DATABASE</ID>
  <OriginalElement />
  <nodes />
  <notes />
  <edges />
  <settings layout="Hierarchic Group" zoom="1.0" x="480.0" y="538.0" />
  <SelectedNodes />
  <Categories>
    <Category>Virtual foreign keys</Category>
  </Categories>
</Diagram>
```

How do I open the file? I don't have access to the project/database from which the file has been generated.

Comment: Do you try to open it inside IDEA? By default IDEA associates UML files with Diagrams.

Comment: Yes - IDEA open empty diagram screen